# A & B inside tikzcd inside environ problem

Tags: errors, environments

Why does the following code produce an error and how can I avoid it? (tested in Overleaf)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{environ}

\newif\ifDraft

\NewEnviron{Details}{\ifDraft\begingroup\color{blue}\BODY\endgroup\fi}

\Drafttrue

\begin{document}

\begin{Details}
$$\begin{tikzcd}
A & B
\end{tikzcd}$$
\end{Details}

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: When `tikz-cd` is in the argument to another command, the `ampersand replacement` trick has to be used.

Comment: I see, thanks! Shall I delete the question as it is a duplicate? (and the \mathrm{} is misleading)